# Fill the Table View after the Web Service response

Tags: swift

I'm calling a web service and I want to show the result in a Table View, what happens is that it seems that the Table View is created before I get the answer from the Web Service. This is my code. The controller is the second of a Tab Controller. Any idea how to get the result of the web service before displaying the tableView? Also try to call the delegate and the datasource from the part that is commented in the viewDidLoad but I don't get a good result either.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var vehiculosTableView: UITableView!
var idEmpresa = ""
var listaVehiculos :[Vehiculo] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let mainTabBar = tabBarController as! MainTabController
    idEmpresa = mainTabBar.idEmpresa
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.forData { (data) in
        let parser = XMLParser(data: data)

        //print(strData)
        let parserDelegate = ParserVehiculoDelegate()
        parser.delegate = parserDelegate
        if
            parser.parse(),
            let result:[Vehiculo] = parserDelegate.vehiculos{
            self.listaVehiculos = result
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.vehiculosTableView.delegate = self
                self.vehiculosTableView.dataSource = self
            }
        }
        else { return }
    }
    //self.vehiculosTableView.delegate = self
    //self.vehiculosTableView.dataSource = self
}

func forData(completion:  @escaping (Data) -> ()) {
    let is_SoapMessage1 = String(format: "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><WSListarVehiculos xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><idEmpresa>%@</idEmpresa></WSListarVehiculos></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>", self.idEmpresa)
    //showToas(message: "\(username!)"+" "+"\(password!)")
    let is_URL1: String = "http://10.0.0.160/WebService.asmx"
    let lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: is_URL1)! as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    lobj_Request.httpMethod = "POST"
    lobj_Request.httpBody = is_SoapMessage1.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    lobj_Request.addValue("10.0.0.160", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    lobj_Request.addValue(String(is_SoapMessage1.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    //lobj_Request.addValue("223", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    lobj_Request.addValue("http://tempuri.org/WSListarVehiculos", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: lobj_Request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        //print("Response: \(response!)")
        var strData: String = String(data: data!, encoding: .ascii)!
        strData = strData.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "\n")
        if let data = data, error == nil {
            completion(data)
        } else {
            print("error=\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
class ParserVehiculoDelegate: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    var currentValue: Vehiculo?
    var vehiculos :[Vehiculo] = []
    var XmlText = ""
    var xmlParse: XMLParser?

func parse() -> [Vehiculo]{
    xmlParse?.delegate=self
    xmlParse?.parse()
    return vehiculos
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    XmlText=""
    if elementName == "Table" {
        currentValue = Vehiculo()
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    XmlText += string
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "idVehiculo" {
        currentValue?.idVehiculo=XmlText
    }
    if elementName == "chapa" {
        currentValue?.chapa=XmlText
    }
    if elementName == "descripcion" {
        currentValue?.descripcion=XmlText
    }
    if elementName == "idEmpresa" {
        currentValue?.idEmpresa=XmlText
    }
    if elementName == "marca" {
        currentValue?.marca=XmlText
    }
    if elementName == "modelo" {
        currentValue?.modelo=XmlText
    }
    if elementName == "Table" {
        if let vehiculo = currentValue{
            vehiculos.append(vehiculo)
        }
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
    print(parseError)
}
}

class Vehiculo{
    var idVehiculo = ""
    var chapa = ""
    var descripcion = ""
    var idEmpresa = ""
    var marca = ""
    var modelo = ""
}

extension SecondViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(self.listaVehiculos.count)
        return self.listaVehiculos.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let vehiculo = self.listaVehiculos[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idVehiculo") as! VehiculoViewCell

    cell.setVehiculo(vehiculo: vehiculo)

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Reload your tableview after you get data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reload your table view once you get data in callback**

```
    self.forData { (data) in
            let parser = XMLParser(data: data)

            //print(strData)
            let parserDelegate = ParserVehiculoDelegate()
            parser.delegate = parserDelegate
            if
                parser.parse(),
                let result:[Vehiculo] = parserDelegate.vehiculos{
                self.listaVehiculos = result
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.vehiculosTableView.delegate = self
                    self.vehiculosTableView.dataSource = self
                    vehiculosTableView.reloadData() // reload your table view
                }
            }
            else { return }
```